# Passing module function to a function in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-marked

I'm not exactly sure what's going on here, but it has been bugging me for a while. The `marked` node markdown parser works like this:

```
var marked = require('marked');
marked.setOptions({ mathjax : false });
```

That all works. But I'm building a plugin system where I want to pass the marked module function into a function from another file and set the options in that function:

```
// main.js
var marked = require('marked');
var plugin = require('./plugin');
plugin(marked);
marked("# my markdown\n $$5 + 5$$", function(err, result) {
  // this result still parses mathjax. Setting the option in the main
  // file will disable mathjax.
  console.log(result);
});

// plugin.js
module.exports = function(marked) {
  marked.setOptions({ mathjax: false });
}
```

The `marked` function is passed correctly to my plugin function, and the `setOptions` function is called, but when I use `marked` afterwards in my main script, the options are not set. If I set the options in the main script, it's working.

I'm a bit unsure of whether `marked` being a `Function` and its implementation of `setOptions()` might be the culprit of this?

Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you understand that it is not working?

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(marked)` in `plugin.js`?

Comment: This should work just fine, something else must be going on?

Comment: Describe "not working." Do you get an error? Is the `marked` function argument some unexpected value? Does your computer monitor turn off when you run the script?

Comment: I updated the question to specify what's not working: Marked is getting passed to my plugin, I can correctly call the setOptions function, but when I use kramed afterwards in my main script, the options are not set. Maybe this relates to how kramed is written? When I console.log kramed, it's typeof Function.

Comment: "*I'm a bit unsure of how `marked` can be Function and still have a `setOptions()` function*" - every function is an object in js, and can have instance properties. Nothing unusual about that.

Comment: I know the basics of prototypical inheritance, but my question was whether or not this is causing my problem.

Comment: No, it's not causing your problem. To be honest, I cannot see what would cause your problem, I cannot reproduce it. Can you maybe post the output of `console.dir(marked)` before and after calling `setOptions` (in both working and non-working versions)?

Comment: Here's a gist that logs the output from inside the plugin (inside.txt) and outside in the main function (outside.txt). I'm using the `kramed` fork of `marked`, but it's the same concept.

Comment: I realized that the problem is that `kramed` and `marked` save their default config NOT on the prototype object, but on the pure function itself. Because of Node's` require` caching behavior, it was sharing the same function reference across all my tests, spilling over the settings. This seems like a really bad implementation. Switching to `markdown-it` immediately fixed it because it works on the prototype instance.

Answer (score 0):

You said you switched to kramed, an [looking at the definition](https://github.com/GitbookIO/kramed/blob/master/lib/kramed.js#L116) of `setOptions` it returns an instance of `kramed`. So setting the options in another file may not mutate the global instance of `kramed` in `main.js`. At the very least changing to the following works:

```
// main.js
var kramed = require('kramed');
var plugin = require('./plugin');
kramed = plugin(kramed);
kramed("# my markdown\n  $$5 + 5$$", function(err, result) { console.log(result); });

//plugin.js
module.exports = function(kramed) {
  return kramed.setOptions({ mathjax: false });
}
```